# User not required to fill out required fields?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

So I got a document library that I made using the Wizard found in Visual Studio 2013 Professional for Sharepoint 2010.

After creating the list I go and add 3 new fields that I need and set them all to required. However when I go look on my deployed Sharepoint site the fields don't show in the properties after I upload a document.

They don't even show if I go and press "Edit Properties" on the file. I am not sure what the problem is here. I didn't edit the Schema.xml and I made all fields using the visual editor.

This is deployed on a Farm Solution not a Sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem on occation. Have you tried to make a new list instance based on your definition? When you create your List Definition with corresponding columns I belive that the Instance that gets created automaticly when you create the Definition is "empty"

I think this resource might be of help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff728096%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Good Luck! //Kodz